# Foam insulation in interior walls

Tags: insulation

If I use foam insulation on the outside (2") and in the 2 x 6 walls (from 4 - 5"), do I need to fill in the leftover space on the inside with fiberglass or Roxul, or just put the vapor barrier over it leaving  1 - 1 1/2" air space?

Comment: What are you trying to do? There's no reason you couldn't have some air space in your walls. You want to avoid creating a layer that has vapor barriers on both sides (thus no way to dry) but that applies whether the layer contains only air or contains air-permeable insulation such as fiberglass or rock wool.

Comment: Where are you from?

Comment: Don't add a vapor barrier unless you're in Canada or farther north.

Answer (score 1):

The space does not have to be filled but should not be between the two foam layers.
The required R value does have to be met.
To find your total R value: add the specified ratings for both foams.
Why are you putting the vapor barrier on the inside? Is this code compliant where you are?